# Excel Sheet Read-Only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

we have an issue that the user once clicked on the excel/word/PPT file it opens as Read Only, the changes made on the file can not be saved to the original file located on the SharePoint library !! but when you open the file uploaded on the SharePoint from the using "open with Explorer" you can edit the file and save the changes. 
Any one can assist?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the document is read only when we open the document in the office application from SharePoint library.

We can click the “Edit Document” to edit the document.

[image]

You could check if there is “Edit Document” when opening the document.

If there is no “Edit Document” when opening the document, to troubleshoot the issue,

check things below:

1. Check if the issue occurs on all documents in the current document library.
2. Check if the issue occurs on other document libraries.
3. In the current document library, delete the document and re-upload the document to check if the same issue will occur.
4. Create a new document library and upload the documents into the new document library to check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: There is no “Edit Document”, and I don't think the issue from the Excel itself, because if I open the document using "open with Explorer" I can edit it, but when I click to edit directly I can't.

Comment: You could create a new document library and check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: even after creating new document library, same issue.